# Gitolite gives error message when pushing gitolite-admin: could not symlink

Tags: git, gitolite

The full error message is:

```
could not symlink /var/lib/gitolite/.gitolite/hooks/common/gitolite-hooked to subdir/myrepo.git/hooks
```

This happens when I do any changes to gitolite-admin and push these changes. What are these hooks for? Do I need them? What's the problem with the symlink?

I have specified another location for my repositories in `$REPO_BASE`, but I made the gitolite user the owner of this path and all repositories using the `chown` command so it shouldn't be a permission problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so I found out why this happened. Probably because I'm a noob with Git. The repositories I had put in $REPO_BASE where ordinary repositories, with the actual source code files directly below the "root" directory.

For example, `/mnt/data/git/repositories/aproject/Main.cpp` and so on. Turns out I need to have the actual repository under that path, so I did (I might just have been able to use the .git-folder for this, but this is how I did it): `git clone --bare aproject.git aproject.git2 && rm -rf aproject.git && mv aproject.git2 aproject.git`.

In short, I did a bare clone of the repository. So now, in `/mnt/data/git/repositories/aproject/` we can actually find the "hooks" folder (which the error message complains it cannot find). After a new push of the gitolite-admin repo, all keys were added to authorized_keys and the error message disappeared.

Comment: Note, I had the same issue. It was easier for me to just delete everything except for ./.git/ in the repo (./), and then move everything from ./git into ./. Finally rmdir the empty .git . Thanks

Comment: Hey, thank you very much. You saved me a ton of time!

Answer (score 3):

I had this same error, it was a permissions issue.

**Make sure that your Project.git is owned by the Git user, not root.**

Thought I would share.

Comment: Same problem here, when I copied repos from an older server over.

Answer (score 0):

This is either a permission issue (which you say it shouldn't be), or a chmod (access) issue.
To be extra sure, you can edit your question with the "ls -alrt' of both directories.
If it fails during the [new repos declaration](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/src/gitolite.pm#L227), it will keep trying to declare them at each new push.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. You are right it could have been a permission error, but it wasn't this time. See my answer (I found the cause!).